# Run several processes in cmd window with ConEmu

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file, conemu

I'm using ConEmu with Windows 8.1. I need to write a BAT-file, which will run ConEmu and open several cmd-shell tabs, running a process in each of it.

Right now my file looks like this:

```
start "ConEmu" "C:\Path\To\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" -cmdlist ^
cmd /K "Process1\Launching\Command"
^|^|^| cmd /K "Process2\Launching\Command"
```

It opens ConEmu, but only with first tab and launched process in it, ignoring the second part of command list. What's wrong?

Comment: Check first what arguments were passed to ConEmu. Use ProcessExplorer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself. Getting rid of spaces before and after commands separator was enough.